# Asp.Net Core 5.0 MVC Web app Ajax post throws an error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I am developing Asp.Net Core 5.0 MVC Web app. I migrated this app from Asp.Net MVC to Asp.Net Core 5.0 MVC. I want to make an Ajax Post from Razor View to controller but it throws "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" error.

I think there is a configuration error because it was working when i using Asp.Net MCV. i tried many variation but cant fix it.

Here is my Starup configuration file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();



        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "home",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        
    }
```

And Here is my Controller;

```
public class SirketController : Controller
    {
    [Route("getSirketSubeleriAsync/{ID}")]
    public IActionResult getSirketSubeleriAsync(long ID)
    {
        
         List<Sube> subeler = sirketService.getSirketSubeleriAsync(ID);
        
         return Json(subeler, "OK");
    } 
}
```

And here is my Ajax Post

```
var formData = '{ID:"' + SirketID + '"}';

            

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("getSirketSubeleriAsync", "Sirket")',
                data: formData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                //beforeSend: function () { $('#loader').show(0); },
                complete: function () { /*$('#spAnime').hide(0);*/ },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found  your Method getSirketSubeleriAsync has a param type long ,but in your ajax
`url: '@Url.Action("getSirketSubeleriAsync", "Sirket")'` param is a string .

So,please try to change your getSirketSubeleriAsync mothod in SirketController :

```
    ...
    public IActionResult getSirketSubeleriAsync(string ID) //long ID
    {
    
       List<Sube> subeler = sirketService.getSirketSubeleriAsync(ID);
    
       return Json(subeler, "OK");
   } 
   ...
```

Comment: Thanx for reply but i tried it throwing same error. Please pay attention to the settings. I think there is an configuration error.